# Implementing the AsyncContext notifier thread

Tags: servlets, asynchronous, comet, tomcat7

Here's the scenario:

- typical web push/comet application where short messages must be pushed at the same time to 3000-4000 connected users;
- moving from 1 thread/connection model to a new implementation using Servlet 3.0 (`AsyncContext`) on Tomcat 7;

One thing I need help to understand is what's the best/safest aproach in implementing the 'notifier' mechanism.

The simplest way is the standard example: 1 thread waiting for a new message and then looping the `AsyncContext`s list and calling `aCtx.getResponse().getWriter().print(message)` for each.

Now, my concern is what happens when there are slow clients connected (and considering we may have 1000s this will always be the case). Could the notifier thread be blocked or waste too much time waiting on these slow clients and affecting everybody? This may be trivial but it's not clear for me if the 'write' is asynch or blocking or if the output buffers would compensate for this at least up to a point.

Or is it better to create for each connected client a `Runnable` (that would do the `aCtx.getResponse().getWriter().print(message)` ) and submit it to an `Executor` using a fixed thread pool? I'm not sure however if creating let's say 4000 `Runnable` at a time (for each message) makes sense or what the performance would be.

And one last thing, does anyone have real/production experience using Tomcat 7 for this sort of app (asynch servlet)? Should i consider it 'production ready in this area? Thanks.

Comment: When you say the message has to be delivered at the "same time" does that mean utilizing a message queue system would not work for your application?  I have utilized beanstalkd to handle the same sort of scenario.